# How to create a c++ type of a list of valid values

Tags: c++, custom-data-type

Hello I am looking for a possibility to create a data-type or something like that in c++ (qt 5.15).
I need to redesign a datastructure in my app for transportation over a REST API.
Therefore I need a "String" variable that can only be of the values "Level1" , "Level2" or "Level3"

How can I accomplish this?

So I need something that solves:
*TLevel m_levelInStructure = "Level1" || "Level2" || "Level3";*

Comment: It looks like you need an [enumerator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Comment: I would use a custom class with `enum` inside and a `string` getter that would return a constant reference to a (static) string constant according to the actual enum value.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Of course! Thanks for hint. I didn't come up the idea of wrapping the enum in a class and creating getters / overwriting the string operator! That totally solves the issue.